# Как использовать сортировку в LiveData, получая данные из Room?

Tags: kotlin, android-room

Итак, принцип работы такой:

1. В DAO есть две query, который возвращают livedata из двух разных таблиц в БД.
2. В репозитории есть две соответствующие им функции для получения этих livedata и отправки в ViewModel.
3. В ViewModel получаю доступ к репозиторию и забираю оттуда эти две функции, возвращающие livedata.
4. В активити есть Observer этого всего из ViewModel.
   В таком простом виде все работает, данные обновляются в реальном времени(хоть при первом запуске лучше отдельно принудительно грузить данные без LiveData, а то задержка в пару секунд уж очень бесит).
   Но есть такая проблема: мне нужно эти данные из двух разных таблиц объединить в один тип данных(для этого уже есть логика), отсортировать и уже отсортированные данные показывать в RecyclerView. Без LiveData это делалось легко, а вот как теперь впихнуть логику объединения и сортировки между 3 и 4 пунктами? Ибо без Observer в ViewModel мне данные из LiveData не вытащить, все время null, а пихать туда LiveData не вариант, ибо "антипаттерн", да и смысл LiveData с его lifecycle-aware теряется в принципе.
   У кого есть какие идеи? Находил тут похожие вопросы, но они мне не помогли.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону `MediatorLiveData`

Comment: @Komdosh так а разве он не служит лишь для объединения нескольких обычных livedata для удобства манипуляций? У меня ведь проблема другого характера. Я пытаюсь найти способ влезть в цепочку между UI и livedata и подредактировать данные.

Comment: Там как раз можно попытаться встроиться в onchange методе и провернуть свою манипуляцию над списком и затем засабмитить новую коллекцию